# Create SFMC data extension from CSV file

Tags: dataextensions, csv, marketing-cloud

I was wondering if it's possible to create an SFMC data extension by way of uploading a .csv file? I have one now with 60 fields which is likely to grow as I continue testing and would very much like the option to have SFMC simply create a data extension with the associated fields, rather than having to create them manually. However, I'm not seeing this option anywhere in the data extension creation dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing built-in the platform to do something like that.

There's also nothing stopping you from writing something (in SFMC or not) with the [**SFMC Web Services**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/) to do it.

I use a combination of Excel and [**LINQPad**](https://www.linqpad.net/) script (using our own version of the SFMC SDK) to create Data Extensions.

Comment: wow that's an excellent idea, hadn't even looked at that as an option...thanks again!